# Conditionally remove rows from dataframe (more than one conditions)

Tags: r, conditional-statements, dataframe

I have searched SO and although there are many QA about conditionally removing rows none of the QA fit my problem.

I have a `data.frame` containing longitudinal measurements of variable `x`, `y` etc... , at various time points `time`, in several subjects `id`. Some subjects experience an event `ev` (denoted as `1`, otherwise `0` at some `time`). I would like to reduce the initial `data.frame` to:

- 1) All rows with subjects that have not experienced an event (ok, thats easy) but also include
- 2) For the subjects that have experienced an event, all rows just prior to the event (that is all rows whith times less that the time of the event of that individual).

so that,

```
testdf<-data.frame(id=c(rep("A",4),rep("B",4),rep("C",4) ),
                   x=c(NA, NA, 1,2, 3, NA, NA, 1, 2, NA,NA, 5), 
                   y=rev(c(NA, NA, 1,2, 3, NA, NA, 1, 2, NA,NA, 5)),
                   time=c(1,2,3,4,0.1,0.5,10,20,3,2,1,0.5),
                   ev=c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1))
```

would reduce to

```
   id  x  y time ev
1   A NA  5  1.0  0
2   A NA NA  2.0  0
3   A  1 NA  3.0  0
4   A  2  2  4.0  0
5   B  3  1  0.1  0
6   C  2  2  3.0  0
7   C NA  1  2.0  0
8   C NA NA  1.0  0
```

Comment: Note that condition 2 implies condition 1, if condition 2 is written as "all rows prior to an event".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution with `subset` and `ave`:

```
subset(testdf, !ave(ev, id, FUN = cumsum))
```

Answer (score 4):

A solution in base:

```
> do.call(rbind, by(testdf, testdf$id, function(x) x[cumsum(x$ev) == 0,]))
     id  x  y time ev
A.1   A NA  5  1.0  0
A.2   A NA NA  2.0  0
A.3   A  1 NA  3.0  0
A.4   A  2  2  4.0  0
B     B  3  1  0.1  0
C.9   C  2  2  3.0  0
C.10  C NA  1  2.0  0
C.11  C NA NA  1.0  0
```

Comment: Or, `testdf[with(testdf, ave(ev, id, FUN = cumsum)) == 0, ]`

Answer (score 3):

This solution using `data.table` seems to work on your `testdf`. The idea is to use `cumsum` to track the positions after the start of the first event.

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(testdf, key=c("id"))
dt.out <- dt[, .SD[cumsum(ev) == 0], by=id]
> dt.out

#    id  x  y time ev
# 1:  A NA  5  1.0  0
# 2:  A NA NA  2.0  0
# 3:  A  1 NA  3.0  0
# 4:  A  2  2  4.0  0
# 5:  B  3  1  0.1  0
# 6:  C  2  2  3.0  0
# 7:  C NA  1  2.0  0
# 8:  C NA NA  1.0  0
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example:

```
> ddply(testdf, .(id), function(z) z[cumsum(z$ev) == 0, ])
  id  x  y time ev
1  A NA  5  1.0  0
2  A NA NA  2.0  0
3  A  1 NA  3.0  0
4  A  2  2  4.0  0
5  B  3  1  0.1  0
6  C  2  2  3.0  0
7  C NA  1  2.0  0
8  C NA NA  1.0  0
```